# How do I perform Non Linear Least Squares in R with a pre determined lag structure

Tags: r, parameters, least-squares, nonlinear-optimization, non-linear-regression

Suppose I want to estimate the parameters of the following model:
$y_t = beta0 (sum_{i=1}^p w(delta;i) x_{t-i})$.

Latex version of the equation: https://i.stack.imgur.com/POOlD.png

Where y_t and x_{t-i} are known data points, wdelta follows an exponential Almon lag structure with two parameters delta1 and delta2(see image). And beta0 is the common parameter.

Generating some data for x and y

```
y <- seq(1:10)
x <- rnorm(10,2,5)
```

The literature suggests estimating the model parameters using NLS and the Gaussian Newton Method. R does have a function gaussNewton however I am not sure how to use this. How do I approach the estimation of the parameters beta0,delta1 and delta2?

Wikipedia suggest: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-linear_least_squares, however I feel like this is not appropriate in this case.
The nls function in R is unable to deal with predefined lag structures so this is not an option either. Maybe I could write out the function in the form of the sum of squared residuals and use the optim function? Another option could be to use the nlm function.

```
nonls <- function(delta1,delta2,i,p) {
  z <- exp(delta1 * i + delta2 *i)
  
  wdelta[i] <- exp(delta1 * i + delta2 *i)/sum(z[1:i])
  
  ssr <- (y[i]- (beta0 * wdelta[i] * x[i:p]))^2
}
 
optim(ssr)
```

I look forward to your suggestions.

Comment: I thinking you might have gotten one of the many helpful statisticians to look at this over at CrossValidated.com. I suspect they would eagerly play "name that method" and you could then search for an R package that provided canned, tested recipes. Or try https://www.google.com/search?q=cran+packages+exponential+Almon+lag+structur&oq=cran+packages+exponential+Almon+lag+structur&aqs=chrome..69i57j33.7462j1j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: I will try this, thank you!